# NoMethod Error in Stripe API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I'm getting an error when canceling a Stripe subscription in my rails app:

> undefined method `subscription' for Stripe::Customer:...

Here's the code:

```
def cancel_subscription
    unless customer_id.nil?
      customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve(customer_id)
      unless customer.nil? or customer.respond_to?('deleted')
        if customer.subscription.status == 'active'
          customer.cancel_subscription
        end
      end
    end
rescue Stripe::StripeError => e
    logger.error "Stripe Error: " + e.message
    errors.add :base, "Unable to cancel your subscription. #{e.message}."
    false
end
```

It used to work just fine...any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind...API update.  Should be:

```
customer.subscription == 'active'
```